# Google Maps v3, custom control with textbox: can't perform input

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I am trying to add a custom control to my google map (v3): I want to have search box just near the other map controls. So I add a div with `<input type="textbox">` on it, and it's being shown on the map. But the problem is that the textbox is inaccessible: I can't type anything inside it, or even focus on it.

```
function SearchBox() {
    var searchTextBox = $('<input type="text" id="txtGeoSearch" />');

    var div = $('<div class="geoSearchBox"></div>')
        .append($('<span>Search:</span>'))
        .append(searchTextBox);

    return div.get(0);
}

// inside init()
geoMap.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(new SearchBox());
```

So what should I do to make my textbox behave like normal one?

Answer (score 7):

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/cFpkt/